# PySpark job on EMR works for smaller files but not bigger ones

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have been getting the below error in EMR when trying to process huge files. The same code works while processing smaller files. This step fails on the repartition step and saving to `AWS S3`. I have checked many configurations on `fs.s3` and none of them worked. Below is the code snippet.

```
 df.repartition(20).write.parquet(f"s3://bucket/path", mode="overwrite")
```

Below is the error trace

```
java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=0, contentLength=52262701904
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.read(S3FSInputStream.java:298)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.fillBuffer(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat.$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1(TextFileFormat.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$.$anonfun$prepareShuffleDependency$6(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1189)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1135)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:752)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5052)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4998)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1486)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.GetObjectCall.perform(GetObjectCall.java:21)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.GetObjectCall.perform(GetObjectCall.java:8)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:114)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:189)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.getObject(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:102)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.GetObjectInputStreamWithInfoFactory.create(GetObjectInputStreamWithInfoFactory.java:63)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.open(S3FSInputStream.java:192)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.retrieveInputStreamWithInfo(S3FSInputStream.java:379)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.reopenStream(S3FSInputStream.java:366)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.read(S3FSInputStream.java:261)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:280)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor452.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionRequestFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionRequestFactory.java:70)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy32.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1311)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1127)
    ... 56 more
"}
21/09/24 13:47:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 111.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 626, executor 1): java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=0, contentLength=52262701904
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.read(S3FSInputStream.java:298)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.fillBuffer(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat.$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1(TextFileFormat.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$.$anonfun$prepareShuffleDependency$6(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1189)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1135)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:752)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5052)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4998)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1486)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.GetObjectCall.perform(GetObjectCall.java:21)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.GetObjectCall.perform(GetObjectCall.java:8)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:114)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:189)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.getObject(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:102)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.GetObjectInputStreamWithInfoFactory.create(GetObjectInputStreamWithInfoFactory.java:63)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.open(S3FSInputStream.java:192)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.retrieveInputStreamWithInfo(S3FSInputStream.java:379)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.reopenStream(S3FSInputStream.java:366)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.read(S3FSInputStream.java:261)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:280)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor452.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionRequestFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionRequestFactory.java:70)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy32.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1311)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1127)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: This is not a full stack trace and doesn't indicate any error. Can you post a better log?

Comment: Also how big are your "huge files"

Comment: Done with adding entire stack trace. Also, the bigger file is around 60GB and the smaller one is 2 GB.